# Standard character set for auto created tables using Kafka and JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, encoding, teradata

We are using `Kafka` and `Confluent JDBC Sink Connector` to export data from `Kafka` topics to a `Teradata` database. Unfortunately I have an issue with the `Auto Create`/`Evolve` feature as this generates tables with a `LATIN` `character set` by default. The workaround is to predefine all the columns in the `JDBC Sink Connector` config and set the value type to `VARCHAR` and character set `UNICODE` manually for each column.

Is there any other way to define a default character set? Preferable per config as I don't have access to the server configuration? Where does this standard behaviour (`LATIN` character set) come from?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: It comes from a user-level default, which will be LATIN if not specified in CREATE USER. It can be changed via `MODIFY USER username AS DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UNICODE;`